# No columns to parse from file with format csv path?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

this is my data:

```
0,1979,21,0
1,1963,37,0
2,1954,46,0
3,1940,60,0
4,1932,68,0
5,1922,78,0
6,1916,84,0
7,1912,88,0
8,1899,100,1
```

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
a,b,i = 'R','R',1
pd.read_csv('contact_simulation/A{0}-B{1}-{2}.csv'.format(a,b,i),header = None)
```

and i get this error

```
pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I have 270 files to parse and get the last line of it,so how can I do it?

Comment: Have you opened the file to check there is actually data in it?

Comment: The configuration of reading file look good. What is the file encoding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333067/pandas-errors-emptydataerror-no-columns-to-parse-from-file there might be some answers here which could help

Comment: I can reproduce your error with an empty file.

Comment: all right, I checked them and found the empty file.